# How to make a popover point to a tableview cell

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, popover

I want a popover to point to a tableview, more specifically to the cell i have just selected.

I can get a popover to appear but dont know what to enter in the

CGRect popRect = CGRectMake();

to get it to point to the cell.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:cell.frame inView:tableView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Which asks for the popover to be presented from the cells frame in the context of the table view (the table view coordinate system).